# How to make sure text processes onchange before form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input with an onchange event. This event is called appropriately provided the text box looses focus. However, when clicking a button for form submission while the text box still has focus, this onchange event is not being called or it is not finishing before submitting the form. What is the best way to make sure this event is processed before submitting the form?

Comment: Use a submit listener either instead or also.

Comment: Try onkeypress event. onkeypress="myFunction()"

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing ajax call in your 'onChange' then that makes complete sense now. You have to wait for the success and only then allow submit. Either disable the submit button until all processing is finished or you could use a promise for the ajax and use it in the submit function (developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/…)

Comment: The code is long. Needless to say there is an ajax call and after the user changes the final value, I need to edit other text box values. Right now I put a confirm prompt which gives the ajax time to complete before the user clicks ok. This seems like a band-aid approach though.

Comment: If you are doing ajax call in your 'onChange' then that makes complete sense now. You have to wait for the success and only then allow submit. Either disable the submit button until all processing is finished or you could use a promise for the ajax and use it in the submit function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I don't know why didn't think of disabling the button. That's brilliant

Comment: do you want to put this comment as an answer? I will mark it as the answer then. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I have, that will be much appreciated, thanks.